# Как добавить стиль родительскому div в зависимости от вложенного input

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

У меня есть такие пункты

- Красный(5)
- Синий(0)
- Черный(4)

Зависимость у меня только одна
это строки 4, 14 и 23

```
<div class="oiu">
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_checkbox">                     
  <li class="woof_term_37 ">
  <div class="icheckbox_flat-blue" >
  <input type="checkbox" id="woof_37_5ddabd90b31f1" class="woof_checkbox_term woof_checkbox_term_37" data-tax="pa_zvet" name="asdf" data-term-id="37" value="37" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
  <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
  </div>
  <label class="woof_checkbox_label " for="woof_37_5ddabd90b31f1">Красный<span class="woof_checkbox_count">(5)</span>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" value="Красный" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_zvet_red">
  </li>

  <li class="woof_term_35 " >
  <div class="icheckbox_flat-blue disabled" style="position: relative;">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="" id="woof_35_5ddabd90b4de9" class="woof_checkbox_term woof_checkbox_term_35" data-tax="pa_zvet" name="qwer" data-term-id="35" value="35" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
  <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
  </div>
  <label class="woof_checkbox_label " for="woof_35_5ddabd90b4de9">Синий<span class="woof_checkbox_count">(0)</span>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" value="Синий" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_zvet_blue">
  </li>
  <li class="woof_term_38 ">
  <div class="icheckbox_flat-blue" style="position: relative;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="woof_38_5ddabd90b541b" class="woof_checkbox_term woof_checkbox_term_38" data-tax="pa_zvet" name="zxcvv" data-term-id="38" value="38" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
  <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
  </div>
  <label class="woof_checkbox_label " for="woof_38_5ddabd90b541b">Черный<span class="woof_checkbox_count">(4)</span>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" value="Черный" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_zvet_black">
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```css
<style>
.icheckbox_flat-blue {
        width: 25px;
    height: 25px;    
}
</style>
```

или тут  - https://jsfiddle.net/gkan10qr/20/
https://jsfiddle.net/gkan10qr/21/

мы имеем  разные `name=`, т.е. мы имеем несколько `name=`

- name="qwer"
- name="asdf"
- name="zxcv"

Нужно к диву

```
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-blue" >
```

добавить класс в зависимости от вложенного ИНПУТ
чтобы получилось

```
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-blue new-style" >
```

чтобы можно было применять  стили типа

```
    .icheckbox_flat-blue.new-style {
          background: #F44336;   
    }
    .icheckbox_flat-blue.asdf {
          background: #F44336;   
    }
    .icheckbox_flat-blue.qwer {
         background: #333;  
    }
    .icheckbox_flat-blue.zxcv {
           background: #4CAF50;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".icheckbox_flat-blue input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
  $(this).closest(".icheckbox_flat-blue").addClass($(this).attr("name"));
});
```